# Replace underscores with ampersands and hyphens with spaces

Tags: str-replace

I have a mysql table that contains words joined by underscores and also words joined by hyphens.

example: Engineering-Service_Civil-Geotech

I am able to replace the underscore with an ampersand and add a space on either side, but im stuck at how to replace the hyphen with one blank space as well.

```
$cleanCat =  str_replace( '_', ' &amp; ', $Cat);
echo $cleanCat;
```

The result of the above code gives me one solution but not both:

**example: Engineering-Service & Civil-Geotech**

Do i have to use a different command to achieve this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cleanCat =  str_replace('-', ' ', str_replace( '_', ' &amp; ', $Cat));
```

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace( '-', ' ', $Cat); or str_replace( '-', ' ', $Cat);`

should work

Comment: Hi Jan, thank you so much for your feedback. Unfortunately i couldnt quite get your code to work, it may have just been the semi colum before the or statement but i got it working with simons. Thanks again though :)